# Does $a^b=a^c$ imply $b^a=c^a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

Does $a^b=a^c$ imply $b^a=c^a$? I can't prove it mathematically. Can anyone show me how to prove this mathematically (if it's true), or disprove it?

(Note: I will delete if duplicate but I couldn't find any)

My attempt:

$a^b=a^c$

$a^{c-b}=1$

That means that either $a=1$ or $c-b=0$

$c-b=0 \implies b=c$

If $a=1$ then $c-b=0 \implies b=c$ is not necessarily true so $a=1$ is a counterexample for $b \ne c$.

Is this right? Is there another way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if a = 1?

Comment: Hint: Let $a = 1$.

Comment: When $a=1$, what do you get?

Comment: $(-1)^2 = (-1)^4$.

Comment: It's very easy to find this, using logarithms $$  b\ln{(a)} = c\ln{(a)} $$ $$ b = c $$ $$ b ^a = c^a $$

Comment: @Dclrk with the condition $a>0$ and $a\ne 1$

Comment: Got to be careful how to define $a^k$ if $a < 0$ but if $a < 0$ then $a = -|a|$ and so $a^k=(-1)^k|a|^k$ and $(-1)^k = \pm$ depending on whether $k$, in its lowest terms, has an even or odd numerator (it isn't defined if the denominator is even).  So $|a^k| = |(-1)^k|a|^k|=|a|^k$. And so for $a\ne \pm; a\ne 0$ we have $a^b=a^c\implies |a|^b=|a|^c \implies b = c$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking $a^b = a^c$ implies that $b = c$ from which $b^a = c^a$ would then follow. But there are exceptions to this. If you can figure out what can go wrong then you can find out when $a^b = a^c$ but $b \ne c$ and then see if you then have $b^a \ne c^a$.

As a hint, examine the following proof:
\begin{align*}
a^b &= a^c \\
b\log(a) &= c\log(a) \\
b &= c.
\end{align*}

This is a correct proof for most values of $a$ but something could go wrong for certain values of $a$. Can you spot it? Then for those certain values can you check if $a^b = a^c$ implies $b = c$ is still true?

Comment: $|a^k| = |a|^k$ so if $a < 0$ and $a^b = a^c$ then $|a^b|=|a^c|$ and $|a|^b = |a|^c|$

Comment: oh I see the restriction if $a=1$ then $\log (a)=\log (1)=0$, so $b$ does not necessarily equal $c$ if $a=1$. Right?

Comment: @AidenChow Correct. $a = 0$ also causes issues and for example $(-1)^2 = (-1)^4$. As long as $a \ne 0$ or $|a| \ne 1$, we have $a^b = a^c$ implies $|a|^b = |a|^c$ implies $b = c$ by taking logs. This is all for real exponents. It's no longer true for complex exponents simply because $e^{2\pi i} = e^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $a,b,c>0$ and $a\ne 1$, $a^b=a^c$ is just $b=c$ ! (Taking the base $a$ logarithm.)

The converse is true, taking the $a^{th}$ root, $b^a=c^a\implies b=c.$

If $a=1$, $a^b=a^c$ is implicit.